# Python: many regexes in a row?

Tags: python, regex, text

I have some text files that are the output of another software. I have a Perl script held together by duct tape that cleans these up with a series of almost 100 regular expressions in a row.

I'm new to Python and wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to handle this than a big block of these, which is lot heavier than the perl construct of: `string =~ s/blah/blah/i;`

```
string = re.sub(r'  +', " ", string, re.I)
string = re.sub(r'(\w)- ', "\1, ", string, re.I)
string = re.sub(r'u-s', "U.S.", string, re.I)
```

For instance some kind of dict with regexes and their replacements? I'm also curious about how calling a function of a module so many times in a row would affect performance?

Comment: No need for a `dict`, but a `list` of two-`tuple`s would make sense.

Comment: How do you run so many regex without running into overlap?

Comment: The source file is a teleprompter script, so many unique formatting codes for teleprompter software are being removed, as well as frequent issues like in the example, a hyphen being used to show a pause instead of a comma. The file is being converted to plain text for human reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place the regular expressions into tuples, then it is an easy matter to iterate over the tuples and perform the replaces.

**Regular Expressions:**

```
import re
regexs = (
    (r'  +', " ", re.I),
    (r'(\w)- ', "\1, ", re.I),
    (r'u-s', "U.S.", re.I),
)
compiled_regexs = [(re.compile(rx[0], rx[2]), rx[1]) for rx in regexs]
```

**Code:**

```
for line in lines:
    for regex, replace in compiled_regexs:
        line = regex.sub(replace, line)
    print(line)
```

**Test Data:**

```
lines = (
    'Quick  Brown  Fox',
    'u-s lazy  dog',
)
```

**Results:**

```
Quick Brown Fox
U.S. lazy dog
```